# Send a JS Array = {} to C# (WebMethod)

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, json

Actually I have a Array declared on JS side like below:

```
 var benefArray = {};
 var benefCount = 0;
 var benefNome = $('#txtBenefNome').val();
 var benefDataNasc = $('#txtBenefDataNasc').val();
 var benefGrauParent = $('#txtBenefGrauParent').val();

 benefCount++;
 benefArray[benefCount] = new Array(benefNome, benefDataNasc, benefGrauParent);

              //Ajax Sender
            function sendAjax(url, parametros, sucesso) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: url,
                    data: parametros,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: sucesso
                });
            };

 sendAjax("Client.aspx/AddClient", "{benefArray: \"" + benefArray + "\"}",
 function (msg) {
                    var retorno = msg.d;
                    alert(retorno);
                });
```

On my C# WebMethod side I Have:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public static string AddClient(object benefArray)
    {
        var t = benefArray;
    }
```

I'm trying to get those values from Javascript, what I have to do?
Any insight on this will be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: `benefArray` isn't an array. It's an object. Each of the members you're assigning to it (`benefArray[benefCount] = new Array(benefNome, benefDataNasc, benefGrauParent);`) is an array. Granted the distinction is a bit subtle in JavaScript as [JavaScript arrays aren't really arrays](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/01/myth-of-arrays.html), but serializers will tend to look at the type to see if it's an array when making serialization decisions, so the distinction could make a difference to what you're doing...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Start by defining a model that will represent the data you are working with so that you work with strong types and get rid of the `object` ugliness on your `AddClient` method:

```
public class Benef
{
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string DataNasc { get; set; }
    public string GrauParent { get; set; }
}
```

then have your web method take an array of this model:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string AddClient(Benef[] benefs)
{
    // TODO: process ...

    // by the way as a result you could also return a strongly 
    // typed model and not only strings 
    // which could be easily manipulated on the client side
    return "some result"; 
}
```

and on the client you would define an array of parameters:

```
var parameters = { 
    benefs: [
        {
            Nome: $('#txtBenefNome').val(),
            DataNasc: $('#txtBenefDataNasc').val(),
            GrauParent: $('#txtBenefGrauParent').val()
        }
    ]
};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'Client.aspx/AddClient',
    data: JSON.stringify(parameters),
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        alert(result.d);
    }
});
```

As far as the `JSON.stringify` method I am using here is concerned it is native in modern browsers. But if you intend to support older browsers it is recommended to include the [json2.js](http://www.json.org/js.html) script to your page.

Comment: Thanks for the workaround Darin! I'll try to do this and give you a feedback.

Comment: Man! You are amazing, this just WORKS! :)

Comment: Just one more thing to end it, May I add more than one "benefs"? Such a list on C# list.add();

Comment: @FelipeKM, of course you can, on the client side simply do this: `var parameters = { benefs: [ { ... }, { ... }, { ... } ] };` where you would obviously replace the `...` by the details of each benef.

Comment: Ok I see, but look, How can I make it generic? I'm mean, can be inserted one or more values, so it need to allow to receive more values, I don't know if you got my point, thanks!

Comment: @FelipeKM, I get your point. You can `push` new elements to the array: `parameters.benefs.push({ Nome: 'foo', DataNasc: 'bar', GrauParent: 'baz' });`.

Comment: Hmm, actually I've a function started by a button that include those values to a table, right? So when it is inserted I storage these values to this mode that you said. I need to make something generic to on each "insert" I add this to the property, gotcha?

Comment: @FelipeKM, ohhh, now I am losing you. I would recommend you starting a new question and explaining in details what you are trying to achieve and showing only the relevant javascript part of it as this is no longer related to ASP.NET.

Comment: Ok Let'do it.
As I said I have a basic client form, on a Benefits area can be added one or more values (Name, Phone and Details). 

I have a function that when the user click on ADD Button it storage these values on a JSON object (Like you shown), but when the user add for the second time I'll lose the firstly adding. Understood?\

Comment: @FelipeKM, the `.push` method allows you to add elements to an existing array.

Comment: Thank you for a COMPLETE answer, with full code example for all portions of the process.  I have looked at a great deal of posts where one portion of the process or another was just brushed over and not explained.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid setting up a class, you can also do this

```
[WebMethod]
public static string AddClient(Hashtable[] benefs)
{       
    var n = benefs["Nome"].ToString();
    return "some result"; 
}
```

Other types would require .ToString() and then Parse().