# Post values form an array of checkboxes

Tags: javascript, ajax, model-view-controller

I've been trying for hours to get the data form an array of checkboxes with the same name.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="node"/>

var selectedValues = [];

             $(document.getElementsByName("node")).each(function () {
            selectedValues.push($(this).checked);
           });

            $.ajax({
                url: "/Summary/Test",
                type: "POST",
                data: selectedValues,
                traditional: true                
            });

public void Test(string [] nodes)
        {
        }
```

What am I doing wrong here? I cant figure out why it's skipping that line.

Comment: Is `.each` a function.?

Comment: yes I tried 5-10 ways to do they half had .each

Comment: @MihaiBratulescu -- `.each` is not a plain JS function.. look in your console, you probably have an error that probably says: `undefined is not a function `

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6403562/send-a-js-array-to-c-sharp-webmethod ?

Comment: Why not $("#formId").serialize() ?

Comment: @mplungjan I would also recommend `serialize`, however maybe OP wants an array of values, then it won't help I guess.

Comment: Then he needs JSON.stringify

Comment: I got rid of the error (edited) but now all I get is undefined instead of true/false

Comment: Which MVC framework are you using?  My guess (if you're using .NET MVC) is that your argument name `nodes` in your `void Test()` isn't mapping because you don't have anything named "nodes" that you are posting to the server.  The ModelBinder looks for a form element matching the name of the argument, which you are not providing. Also, putting the values into an array is unnecessary as serialize will do the work for you.  http://jsfiddle.net/cL8f3fo7/1/

Comment: @xDaevax serialize is only giving me the checked ones (I need all) and I even changed it to `object [] nodes` I just cant seem to be able to sent `[false, false, false, false]` to the controller it's always null.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to collect an array of checked checkboxes values, you can use mep method:

```
var selectedValues = $('[name=node]:checked').map(function() {
    return this.value;
}).get();
```

assuming you are using jQuery (?).

Or in plain javascript it's pretty much the same:

```
var selectedValues = [],
    nodes = document.querySelectorAll('[name=node]');

Array.prototype.slice.call(nodes).forEach(function(el) {
    if (el.checked) {
        selectedValues.push(el.value);
    }
});
```

AJAX:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Summary/Test",
    type: "POST",
    data: {nodes: selectedValues},
    traditional: true             
});
```

Comment: And to pass this array to the server you need json

Comment: thanks u got me closer the answer was: `var selectedValues = $(document.getElementsByName("node")).map(function () {
                return this.checked;
            }).get();`

Answer (score 0):

You can't name all your checkboxes the same, only the last value will be submitted.  Change each one to:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="node[]" />
```

That will create an array of selected values.

Comment: That is as far as I can see only needed in PHP when not using ajax

Comment: how can this be different? they still have the same name but a different one now

Comment: This answer appears to be incorrect (See the note here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html in section 17.2.1 under checkboxes).  The default behavior of checkboxes submitted in a form is to append the same name in the submitted form with multiple different values.  It won't submit only the last one.  It us up to the server-side how to process the form elements. Radio buttons with the same name are mutually exclusive but not checkboxes.